# "A"/"an" in front of a noun

Tags: determiners

Which sentence is grammatically correct or preferred?

> 1. Emerald is a delicate and brittle gemstone.
> 2. **An** emerald is a delicate and brittle gemstone.

My kids and even one of their teachers have challenged me on this question!

I voted for #2 while the rest voted for #1.

Cheers,

Forrest (The dad)

Comment: I'd prefer 'Emeralds are delicate and brittle gemstones' over either. Kind of like saying "Roses are red" instead of '(A) rose is red'.

Comment: I would probably opt for 1., when you are referring to emerald as a raw, uncut material. I'd prefer 2. For the cut stone, or jewel.

Answer (score 2):

The American comedian Groucho Marx famously said, "Outside of a dog, a book is a man's best friend. Inside of a dog it's too dark to read."  Humor aside, no one would take this to mean one specific book or dog.  Same with emeralds.  Whereas gold is used as a mass noun, emerald is not. (In fact, "a gold" would be wrong, unless gold is used as an adjective.) Therefore, Sentence 1 sounds wrong.  (At least to my New York ear.)  Thus, "emerald" must be used as a count noun, as in Sentence 2, or the plural version given by Tushar Raj in the comment.

I will allow that it may sound different in other countries.

Comment: +1 for the Marx reference, which is surprisingly apt here!

Answer (score 1):

The first one makes more sense, but I agree with Tushar Raj that the sentence is best recast.

In your examples, the first "emerald" names a type of stone and is used like "gold" would be in "Gold is a precious and valuable metal." "An emerald" would talk about *one* stone and make no sense here because you are clearly discussing emeralds as a type of stone.